# How to bulk delete from a JPA repository in Spring Data receiving a list filled with one of the properties from my Entity class

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity that has four properties, (vehicle, unit, date and id). Primary key is the ID.
I want to delete rows from the database based on the vehicle list provided to me via a request body.

How can I take all the lists and use them to delete data from the database at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "delete...By" query in your Entity repository that takes a List of Vehicle as a parameter and deletes all entities that their Vehicle is contained in that List.
Something like this should work:

void deleteAllByVehicle(List<Vehicle> vehicles);

The documentation contains more options:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Comment: Thanks i did the same , Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Is this approach will delete all with duplicate values if we say I have two same records and I want to delete them by `name` and I use `deleteAllByName(String name)` it will delete all with same name or will return an exception

Answer (score 0):

you can use JPQL to provide custom query

```
@Query(delete from Entity e where e.idvehicle = :id)
void deleteByVehicle(@Param("id") int idvehicle);
```

now you can just pass the id of the Vehicle like that:

```
deleteByVehicle(vehicle.getId());
```